# Is possible to add an UIImageView to an UINavigationBar title?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have an UINavigationBar, and I'm trying to add the user avatar to before the text, and I want 't so it's just before, and thought if I add it with IB, if the tabBar title is longer it would look ugly, so how could I add it on the front of the navBar? It would look like this of Osfoora:

[image: image before title]

Answer (score 1):

You could add `UIImageView` in the `titleView`  property of `UINavigationBar`.
**myImageView** is type of `UIImageView`.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView;
```

Comment: but does that conserve the title too?

Comment: @zad0xsis : Do you want the text along with UIImangeView in title ?

Comment: @zad0xsis :if yes : Use `UIView` as container and add both as subview  `UIImageView` and `UILabel`. Add this container view to your bar `titleView`.

Comment: yeah I would like to, any help to achieve ir right? I already tried that with no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

add it as a barbutton image if you are not using any barbutton.